# Magento 2 - The right way to get a product attribute value

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, attributes, dropdown-options

I'm wondering if there's a right way to get the value of a product attribute, in a **generic** way.

**EDIT:**
*Or whatever I can use to get the info from a dropdown or text field using the same mechanism*

I know I can do:
`$product->getData('attribute_code')`

But if the code it's a dropdown select then I'll be getting a value which doesn't represent really what the users selected.
For example in a dropdown to select a t-shirt size options would be (s,l,xl) and internal values (1,2,3)

It's a way to know how to get the attribute type to later identify what I should be looking for or the right way to pick the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for dropdown use this code

```
<?php echo $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); // dropdown attribute"?>
```

the other code only displays the ID from the database tabel when used for dropdown.
this is why you get 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Actually magento internally use magic method so if your attribute code is `tshirt_size` then magic method would be `getTshirtSize()`

if you want to get a text of `tshirt_size` attribute then you can use the below method which is return selected size (i.e. l)

```
$product->getAttributeText('tshirt_size');
```

if you want that value of `tshirt_size` then you can use the below method.

```
$product->getTshirtSize();
```

Comment: Does this work if TshirtSize would be a Text Field or a Select Dropdown? Sorry not very familiar yet